# two dimensional array of integer from controller to view to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, multidimensional-array

I am working on a javascript graph which requires data as the following format-

```
data = [[int, int],[int, int], [int, int], ....]
```

In action method, I have the following code-

```
 List<GraphData> data = new List<GraphData>(); // GraphData is a model
 data.Add(new GraphData() { PositionNo =1, Quantity = 10 }); 
 data.Add(new GraphData() { PositionNo =2, Quantity = 20 });
 ViewBag.GraphData= data; //sending to view
```

I am stuck here. How can I send this data from razor to javascript array?

Comment: Can't you add it to the `Model`/`ViewBag` and access it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var GraphData=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.GraphDatas));

var graphData=[];

for (var i = 0; i < GraphData.length; i++) {
    graphData[i]=[];
    graphData[i].push(GraphData[i].PositionNo);
    graphData[i].push(GraphData[i].Quantity);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, in your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.GraphData))];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your action method from your javascript:

```
public ActionResult GetGraphData()
{
  List<GraphData> data = new List<GraphData>(); // GraphData is a model
  data.Add(new GraphData() { PositionNo =1, Quantity = 10 }); 
  data.Add(new GraphData() { PositionNo =2, Quantity = 20 });
  ViewBag.GraphData= data; //sending to view

 return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

**Script:**

```
$.get("/Controller/GetGraphData", function(data) {
    //access data[0].PositionNo
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[,];
@foreach(var data in ViewBag.GraphData as List<GraphData>)
{
<text>
var d="@data";
array.push(d);
</text>
}
```